# How can I perform cross browser testing when using Subversion as my version control system?

Tags: windows, macos, svn, cross-browser, cornerstone

I have recently installed subversion and nginx server on my machine (macbook pro). I'm fairly new to subversion as a whole and have just built a single webpage through this version control system, and now I'm faced with the task of testing it in all of the relatively modern web browsers. My biggest concern, as far as browser compatibilty is concerned, is Internet Explorer which, in order to test, I need Windows. I have Windows 7 installed on my mac via Virtual Box, and *herein lies my problem*.

I have not committed the new page I've just created to the repository, by the request of the client. Because of this, as far as I know, I have no URL to use for testing in IE Tester, Firefox for Windows, etc. **How can I test this 1 page site's browser compatibility with without having committed any changes to the repository?**

I can test it easily on my machine using MacOS, by just typing in local.*****.org and it shows up. Again, windows is my issue. This project is due this Thursday (5/24/12), so you're help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have VirtualBox running on your Mac? Then you *should* be able to reach it from within the VM... *how* to do that I'm not sure though

Comment: I fail to see the relationship between SVN and the testing of a web page. You don't need to put a web page under SVN to make it available on a web server.

Comment: Q: What exactly does testing your web page on different browsers have to do with SVN?  You test your web page everywhere (on all applicable browsers).  But you typically checkin/checkout your source in only one place (perhaps a TortoiseSVN client running on your Mac).

Comment: @Pekka Maybe, then, a better question woud be how can I access my server from VirtualBox?

Comment: @JBNizet It's on my local server, but I don't know how I can access it from my virtual machine without having to install nginx on my VM. That's what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @paulsm4 I've been using SVN via cornerstone, my issue I think may be being able to access the server from the virtual machine installed on my mac. I'm used to just typing the URL into IE Tester and testing that way, now the URL that works on Chrome Mac, isnt' working in my virtual machine.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/310697/connect-to-the-host-machine-from-a-virtualbox-guest-os

Comment: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-network-sharing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Developing and testing your web page is different from managing your web page source. In other words, testing web pages != using SVN.

2) If you've not actually been able to use SVN yet - and if your client has no preferences - then please try TortoiseSVN:

http://scplugin.tigris.org

3) Please post back any specific questions you have about installing/using SVN.

Comment: I've been using SVN via cornerstone, my issue I think may be being able to access the server from the virtual machine installed on my mac. I'm used to just typing the URL into IE Tester and testing that way, now the URL that works on Chrome Mac, isnt' working in my virtual machine.

Thank you *very* much for you help!

Comment: I think the thing is that once he commits the source, it becomes somewhat public. He wants to test the site in IE before it leaves his machine.

Comment: Fair enough.  So the problem is actually IP connectivity with your VM, correct?  1) Your initial goal: you must be able to "ping" from VBox.  2) Here's a good link:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/virtualbox-guest-additions/

Answer (score 1):

If the site uses any scripting languages like PHP, and/or databases, you need to get those setup correctly first. If your website consists of just HTML/CSS/JS... then you can access the website via either of these methods:

- Enable Web Sharing (System Preferences > Sharing > Web Sharing). Then type in the IP shown there into your browser in VirtualBox and it should load. (This is probably easier than trying to get nginx configured, though it might very well load if you just type in your machine's IP.)
- In VirtualBox, select your VM (powered off), Settings > Shared Folders. Add your website's root directory. Launch the VM, then browse to it within the VM and open up your files there for testing.

My current environment is setup like this:
- Local dev machine with git & SVN
- Remote DB server
- Remote web server
- Web server mounts local dev machine's www folder as a volume and serves the PHP pages from there
- Load web browser in VMs or any other machines. Edit hosts file if need be for local routing.